# How to write a string to file on ftp with pysftp?

Tags: python, stringio, pysftp

I have a large xml file stored in a variable. I want to write it directly to an ftp using pysftp.
I believe I need to use the pysftp.putfo and this needs a file like object. Here is a minimal example:

```
from io import StringIO
from pysftp import Connection, CnOpts

cnopts = CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys = None
with Connection('localhost'
                    ,username= 'admin'
                    ,password = 'test'
                    ,cnopts=cnopts
                    ) as sftp:
        sftp.putfo(StringIO('xml string'))
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Expected unicode or bytes, got None
```

What am I doing wrong? And is there maybe a simpler and better way of achieving my goal of writing a string variable to a file on an ftp?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found one solution, not sure it is the best:

```
from io import StringIO
from pysftp import Connection, CnOpts

cnopts = CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys = None
with Connection('localhost'
                ,username= 'admin'
                ,password = 'test'
                ,cnopts=cnopts
                ) as sftp:

    f = sftp.open('/folder/filename.xml', 'wb')
    f.write('xml string')
```

Edit: Discovered why there is no good solution for this. Most FTP-servers will demand that you put a file directly, probably to avoid an undending stream. So my final solution was to create the file locally and use pysft put().

Comment: Really helpful.

Comment: Hi, Could I have a question? @Stian

Comment: Sure, if it is related to this :)

Answer (score 18):

Your first approach was valid, just specify a filename. In-memory files have no default names, and pysftp doesn't know how to name destination file.

```
from io import StringIO
from pysftp import Connection

with Connection('localhost', ...) as sftp:
    sftp.putfo(StringIO('xml string'), 'test.txt')
```

It should just work. Also, as a side note - Paramiko (library used by pysftml) `put` operation is under the hood calling `putfo`, it's just a thin wrapper. So from the server perspective, it's totally transparent if a file was uploaded directly from FS or from memory.